# PaperClip 6.0 not supporting base64 encoded file upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, paperclip

I am using the paperclip 6.0.0 gem and I want to support uploading of documents using a data URI or base64 encoded string in rails application.

Referred : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2575

My app/intializers/paperclip.rb has the following:

Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register

My model looks like this:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :doc, :restricted_characters => nil
end
```

My parameter looks like this:

```
doc => { data:application/octet-stream;name=testing.json.jbuilder;base64,anNvbi50eXBlICdTaW5nbGVDb2x1bW4nDQpqc29uLnN0eWxl ..... }
```

I am getting the following error in console:

> Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "data:application/octet-stream;name=testing.json.jbuilder;base64,anNvbi50eXBlICdTaW5nbGVDb2x1bW4nDQpqc29uLnN0eWxl ..... ")

Not sure if it has anything to do with newer version ...

Thanks.

Comment: Paperclip is deprecated so I will recommend you to use ActiveStorage https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#deprecated

Comment: you can use carrierwave https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Answer (score 2):

They do support it but you have to enable a configuration by adding `Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register` in `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`.

See the issue here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2575.